# A working template-engine for IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, template-engine

I'd love to use a nice template-engine with IronPython but havent succeded doing so. Would be best to be able to without needing to add Python standard lib's. Dont know if that's possible.

I like the Ruby Erb syntax, and hoped to be able to use something similar.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid the standard library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My personal favourite is [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), but it's much closer to Django syntax than to ERB syntax ([Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) seems reasonably close in that respect). You can take a look at [this question about Python templating engines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98245/what-is-your-single-favorite-python-templating-engine) for more ideas.

I can vouch for Jinja2 working on IronPython. It does need the standard library (and I'd guess most of the others do too), and beware of [this bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/27383) if you're running IronPython < v2.7b1 (see the comments for a workaround specific to Jinja2 for earlier releases of IronPython), as well as [this `unicode` bug](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/workitem/29505), but otherwise it works great.

One thing to keep in mind is that template engines tend to import a lot of code (even if it's only standard libraries), which makes them slow to load on IronPython, but fast after the initial JIT compilation.

Comment: Could you tell us how you used Jinja2 in IronPython? Also the link to the discussion of other engines is broken (since StackOverflow only values information you can already find in a specific product's manual).

Comment: @Derf: Ah, too bad about the link. The top answer was Jinja, followed by the built-in string interpolation in Python, followed by Genshi, followed by Mako. It's been a while since I integrated Jinja2, but I remember it being fairly straightforward except for that bug I linked, and another that I forgot to link but added just now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - the built in way is conveniant enough for my needs:

```
def content(result):  
    return """  
    <p>Thank you for posting!</p>  
    <p>Result : {result}</p>  
    """.format(result=result)
```